# What's the best way to approach asking a question that needs to be asked again because of age?

Tags: discussion

I need to ask a question that has been asked in the past.

[How to let authors only see website stats for their posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26865/how-to-let-authors-only-see-website-stats-for-their-posts)

However that question is more than 3 years old. Since significant technical advances have been made since 2011, it's quite possible that there is now a solution for this when before there was not.

How should I go about breathing life into this topic? A new question? Or, should I edit that question and bring it up to date and possibly give it a bounty?  Doing so I would have to alter it quite a bit based on my needs, and the OP may not appreciate that. Or is that something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the details of your and the old question:

- If your question is just *closely related*, but different, then go and ask a new question. You can reference/link to the older, related question to make clear that it's not a duplicate question. Best would be to explain the difference to the older question
- If it is the exact same question and you think the answers could still be better, please just add a bounty.
- If you are sure that the older questions answers are (technically) outdated, then go with the first option: Ask a new one, reference to the old one. Point is, that new answers might be different when it comes to depth and detail. Also you can't accept a new answer that works with the current state of the core API as the old question was not asked by you.
- If the older question is your question, then please go and edit it, offer a bounty and explain what has changed since then and what does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the question might help, upvoting would be better, a bounty would be brilliant. Any activity will pull it up on to the frontpage where there's recent activity making it more visible

But

The question requires an answer that would be large. For example, I would imagine something like this:

http://www.highposition.com/blog/how-to-send-author-content-groups-wordpress-google-analytics/

Being exploited. But then you've get to write code to:

- Create API keys and developer app
- Authenticate with Google
- Keep the Google API tokens setup and refreshed
- Add the necessary google analytics tags and ammendments on author archives and posts
- Interface with the Google Analytics API
- Pull down the information
- Add an admin page
- Put a js chart on said page

Which would be a hefty answer, requiring high level PHP knowledge dealing with a non-WordPress API.

Instead I would suggest this question needs breaking into smaller ones such as:

- How to add an admin menu
- How to use and authenticate the Google PHP API ( Offtopic on this site )
- How to grab data from a content group on google analytics ( Offtopic on this site )
- How to specify a content group ( Offtopic on this site )
- Displaying a JS chart ( Offtopic on this site )

With that in mind, it's unlikely we will have an answer to the question soon.